# Bundled React files in PHP application?

Tags: php, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a PHP HRM system and trying to integrate resources scheduler developed in React.
I have bundled all the JS and CSS in seperate files using Webpack.

Simplified folder structure:

```
admin
  -index.php
scheduler (react's part)
  -bundled.js
  -bundled.css
```

What i need to achieve is to include those bundled files to display in index.php, which is outside React's directory (obviously). I was thinking to include them as follows:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>React Big Scheduler Examples</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../scheduler/bundled.css">
    <script type="text/babel" src="../scheduler/bundled.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

bundled.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Basic from './Basic'
import Locale from './Locale'
etc imports....

render((
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Basic}/>
        <Route path="/readonly" component={Readonly}/>
        <Route path="/locale" component={Locale}/>
        <Route path="/views" component={Views}/>
        etc routes....
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

bundled.css

```
body {
   backgroud-color: grey;
}

etc styles....
```

As I have tested in Developer tools the paths are correct and no errors are shown in console.
Tho, nothing is being rendered to `<div id="root"></div>` in index.php.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you use really bundled js file, because bundled.js file should contain all imports packages codes and be compressed

Comment: sry, first time using webpack, so finally got around right webpack.config.js settings to bundle the file properly and now react renders root id as expected :)
thanks for your help, it made me overlook bundling process!